# Jqplot Gauge Meter issue

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to display jqplot gauge meter on my dashboard, i have managed to get one gauge working but my data is like 4 different guages needed,

Does anyone knows how to draw more than 1 guage , my code below:

data = [20,12,12,23];

```
 $.each(data,function(key,value) {

    plot3 = $.jqplot('dashboard',[[value]],{
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                intervals:[200, 300, 400, 500],
                label: "Pounds",
                intervalColors:['#66cc66', '#93b75f', '#E7E658', '#cc6666']
            }
        }
    });

 });`
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart_1', [[value]],{
[snip]

plot2 = $.jqplot('chart_2', [[other_value]] ,{
[snip]
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div id="chart_1" style="height:240px;width:380px;"></div>

<div id="chart_2" style="height:240px;width:380px;"></div>
```

Should do you.